# Distribute value equally across NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                     var_value
2016-07-01 05:10:00      809.0
2016-07-01 05:15:00        NaN
2016-07-01 05:20:00        NaN
2016-07-01 05:25:00        NaN
2016-07-01 05:30:00        NaN
2016-07-01 05:35:00        NaN
2016-07-01 05:40:00        NaN
2016-07-01 05:45:00        NaN
2016-07-01 05:50:00        NaN
2016-07-01 05:55:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:00:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:05:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:10:00      185.0
2016-07-01 06:15:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:20:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:25:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:30:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:35:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:40:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:45:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:50:00        NaN
2016-07-01 06:55:00        NaN
2016-07-01 07:00:00        NaN
2016-07-01 07:05:00        NaN
```

I want to distribute the 809.0 and 185.0 evenly across the rows. So my resulting dataframe should look like:

```
               var_value
7/1/2016 5:10    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:15    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:20    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:25    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:30    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:35    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:40    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:45    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:50    67.42 
7/1/2016 5:55    67.42 
7/1/2016 6:00    67.42 
7/1/2016 6:05    67.42 
7/1/2016 6:10    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:15    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:20    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:25    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:30    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:35    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:40    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:45    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:50    15.42 
7/1/2016 6:55    15.42 
7/1/2016 7:00    15.42 
7/1/2016 7:05    15.42
```

The number of rows between the known values that need to be distributed (so the NaNs in this case) can differ. In this case it is nicely 11 unknowns, but it could be 10 or 3 or 7, etc.

Any help on solving this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) `NaN` values and then divide by `len` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['var_value'] = df.var_value.ffill()
df['var_value'] = df['var_value'] / df.groupby('var_value')['var_value'].transform(len)

print (df)
                     var_value
2016-07-01 05:10:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:15:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:20:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:25:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:30:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:35:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:40:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:45:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:50:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 05:55:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 06:00:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 06:05:00  67.416667
2016-07-01 06:10:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:15:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:20:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:25:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:30:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:35:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:40:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:45:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:50:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 06:55:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 07:00:00  15.416667
2016-07-01 07:05:00  15.416667
```

Comparing solutions:

`len(df)=24`:

```
In [18]: %timeit (jez(df))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit (pir(df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.92 ms per loop
```

`len(df)=24k`:

```
In [21]: %timeit (jez(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.49 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit (pir(df1))
1 loop, best of 3: 590 ms per loop
```

Code for timings:

```
#if need comapre 24k
#df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.copy()
def jez(df):
    df['var_value'] = df.var_value.ffill()
    df['var_value'] = df['var_value'] / df.groupby('var_value')['var_value'].transform(len)
    return df    

def pir(df):
    df = df.fillna(0).groupby(df.var_value.notnull().cumsum()).transform(lambda x: x.mean())
    return df    


print (jez(df))
print (pir(df1))
```

Comment: This should be the answer.  Unfortunately, I can only upvote you once.  I like the posting of complete timing code.  I'll start doing that.

Comment: Thank you. I was very surprised difference in timings- first I think it will be very similar.

Comment: How if the series is [np.nan, 3, 3]?

Answer (score 3):

```
df.fillna(0).groupby(df.notnull().cumsum()).transform(lambda x: x.mean())

2016-07-01 05:10:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:15:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:20:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:25:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:30:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:35:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:40:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:45:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:50:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 05:55:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 06:00:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 06:05:00    67.416667
2016-07-01 06:10:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:15:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:20:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:25:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:30:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:35:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:40:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:45:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:50:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 06:55:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 07:00:00    15.416667
2016-07-01 07:05:00    15.416667
Name: var_value, dtype: float64
```

#### Explanation

- `df.notnull().cumsum()` creates a series that I can `groupby` with
- `df.fillna(0)` ensures that the `NaN`s are included as `0` when I calculate the `mean`
- `transform(lambda x: x.mean())` calculates the `lambda` function for each element in the group.

#### `df.notnull.cumsum()`

```
2016-07-01 05:10:00    1
2016-07-01 05:15:00    1
2016-07-01 05:20:00    1
2016-07-01 05:25:00    1
2016-07-01 05:30:00    1
2016-07-01 05:35:00    1
2016-07-01 05:40:00    1
2016-07-01 05:45:00    1
2016-07-01 05:50:00    1
2016-07-01 05:55:00    1
2016-07-01 06:00:00    1
2016-07-01 06:05:00    1
2016-07-01 06:10:00    2
2016-07-01 06:15:00    2
2016-07-01 06:20:00    2
2016-07-01 06:25:00    2
2016-07-01 06:30:00    2
2016-07-01 06:35:00    2
2016-07-01 06:40:00    2
2016-07-01 06:45:00    2
2016-07-01 06:50:00    2
2016-07-01 06:55:00    2
2016-07-01 07:00:00    2
2016-07-01 07:05:00    2
Name: var_value, dtype: int64
```

---

Comment: thanks this solution worked... based on timing done by @jezrael I picked that one as the answer, since it seems a bit more performant.